# Mule: Custom SOAP connector with WSDL file

Tags: mule, mule-component

There are 2 ways for creating a custom SOAP connectorn using wsdl file: 1) SOAP connect - importing a wsdl file 2) SDK based using Apache CXF. SOAP connect is pretty easy process to build a connector but with Apache CXF , its little complex. What is the difference between the two ways or advantages of one over another?

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of using SOAP Connect is that you can re-use and distribute your generated connector easily to allow others to connect the web service easily in Mule. With an SDK based approach it takes longer and is not as easy to reuse and distribute.